# Quando devo usar o snippet e quando não devo?

Tags: debate, suporte, stack-snippets

Existem várias perguntas no Stack usando o *snippet*, várias delas fazem bom uso, mostrando elementos visuais, ajudando a entender melhor o problema/solução.

Mas e quando o problema não traz elementos visuais, ou é simplesmente uma função *JavaScript* que não pode ser executada no *snippet* (exemplo: uma chamada ajax em http://localhost:8000/pacoca), não seria ideal apenas destacar esse trecho como código?

Digo isso pois já vi várias questões com *snippet* desnecessário na fila de aprovação, eu deixo o trecho destacado como código sempre quando é esse o caso. Estou fazendo certo?

Comment: Relacionado: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/4204/qual-o-recomend%C3%A1vel-usar-o-stack-snippet-ou-outra-ferramenta

Comment: Hoje houve um caso do tipo: http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/5742/criar-um-t%C3%B3pico-no-meta-para-tutoriais-referentes-ao-site#comment21875_5742 interessante a pergunta pouco tempo depois :P

Comment: Acho que o snippets deve ser usado somente pra códigos html, js e css que possam ser executáveis, para outras linguagens, existem uma pancada de sites pela web que também conseguem emular... http://stackoverflow.com/a/4616435/3956218

Comment: Tem muitos recursos interessantes no Stack, porém se fizer mal uso deles vira um problema :/

Comment: Não diria que é uma problema, mas se houver uma orientação por parte dos mais experientes para com os mais novos, todos saímos ganhando :D

Comment: Só pra elucidar, olhe: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/182079/renderizar-html-vindo-do-banco-de-dados-usando-angular-1-6-1

Comment: @MarceloBonifazio belo uso xD

Comment: Fiz um exemplo complexo usando o snippets, inclusive emulando a minha requisição http com dados que poderiam vir no meu exemplo, se eu não usasse o snippets, provavelmente seria MUITO difícil conseguir a ajuda de alguém.... a maioria das pessoas pode sim criar exemplos bem complexos usando o snippets, mas a maioria sente preguiça.... ai caem naqueles famosos http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Answer (score 21):

Snippets são legais quando usados nos lugares certos, mas snippets desnecessários são muito chatos, irritantes e infelizmente recorrentes.

Para saber se o snippet deve ser usado, marque verdadeiro ou falso para cada uma das afirmações abaixo:

1. O código não é executável na forma em que foi postado.
2. O código contém pelo menos algum trecho escrito em alguma linguagem que não seja JavaScript, HTML, CSS ou SVG.
3. O código depende de recursos externos (imagens, CSS, bibliotecas, AJAX, qualquer coisa) que não estão na sua pergunta ou resposta e nem são por ele baixados.
4. O código precisa acessar recursos externos, mas eles não estão disponíveis publicamente na internet.
5. O código precisa acessar recursos externos, mas a política de CORS não permite que eles sejam baixados.

Se você responder "falso" para **todas** as afirmações acima, então você **pode** usar snippets. Caso contrário (pelo menos uma é verdadeira), então não use snippets.

Comment: Concordo, no geral uso snippets apenas com códigos html para facilitar. Se for apenas uma função javascript  (claro com exceções se printar no console) procuro deixar apenas como código. Snippet é bom, porém muita gente usa muito errado :/

Comment: Não entendi muito bem o item 3. Poderia explicar melhor a parte de **não estão na sua pergunta**?

Comment: @Randrade Por exemplo, um javascript que faz download de uma imagem em `http://example.com/images/teste.png` - A imagem não está na pergunta ou resposta, mas o link para ela está e o código vai baixar isso.

Comment: @Randrade - [um exemplo concreto](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/99999/132) - as imagens não estão na minha resposta, mas o código do snippet faz download delas. Neste caso específico, se o código não fizesse o download, a execução do código como snippet deixaria de ser interessante.

Comment: @VictorStafusa Enendi. Concordo com seus pontos.