# Resultado da Eleição para Moderador 2018

Tags: debate, eleição

A [3ª eleição do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3) chegou ao fim. Depois da contagem de votos, nós temos novo moderador:

[image: Bacco]

Essa é nossa nova [equipe de moderação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators). É hora de dar boas vindas, e parabéns, a quem chega. Obrigado também a todos os outros candidatos, que se dispuseram a ajudar ainda mais o SOpt.

Obrigado ao utluiz, que vai deixar de ser moderador após 3 anos de serviço.

Para ver mais detalhes, basta fazer download do [arquivo de auditoria](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/election/3), ou [ver o resumo online](https://www.opavote.com/results/6065212453027840/0).

Comment: Uia! Agora eu preciso reler o manual de instruções então, mais uma dezena de vezes :D

Comment: @Bacco parabéns meu amigo!

Comment: Muito grato a todos pela confiança, agora é que (re)começa o trabalho.

Comment: Parabéns Bacco!!

Comment: @Bacco, parabéns.

Comment: Parabéns,  @Bacco. Use sua habilidade e conhecimento para aprimorar o site. Make SOPT Great Again!

Comment: Parabéns Bacco!

Comment: Parabéns @Bacco, sucesso nessa nova missão!

Comment: Parabéns Bacco!

Comment: Muitos parabéns Bacco! :)

Comment: Um abraço especial para o @utluiz

Comment: Parabéns @Bacco

Comment: Parabéns @Bacco!!!

Comment: @Bacco Parabéns e que corra tudo pelo melhor! :)

Comment: Parabéns @Bacco.

Comment: Parabéns @Bacco! O Stack é uma plataforma incrível e essa é realmente uma posição de muita importância.

Comment: Uia! Mais um Jurássico! Parabéns @Bacco! Você é certamente o Deus do vinho mais apropriado para o cargo ;).

Answer (score 29):

```js
// Click "Congratulations!" to play animation
//https://codepen.io/JoeHastings/pen/yeeqNv
$(function() {
 var numberOfStars = 20;
 
 for (var i = 0; i < numberOfStars; i++) {
   $('.congrats').append('<div class="blob fa fa-star ' + i + '"></div>');
 } 

 animateText();
 
 animateBlobs();
});

$('.congrats').click(function() {
 reset();
 
 animateText();
 
 animateBlobs();
});

function reset() {
 $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
  TweenMax.set($(this), { x: 0, y: 0, opacity: 1 });
 });
 
 TweenMax.set($('h1'), { scale: 1, opacity: 1, rotation: 0 });
}

function animateText() {
  TweenMax.from($('h1'), 0.8, {
  scale: 0.4,
  opacity: 0,
  rotation: 15,
  ease: Back.easeOut.config(4),
 });
}
 
function animateBlobs() {
 
 var xSeed = _.random(350, 380);
 var ySeed = _.random(120, 170);
 
 $.each($('.blob'), function(i) {
  var $blob = $(this);
  var speed = _.random(1, 5);
  var rotation = _.random(5, 100);
  var scale = _.random(0.8, 1.5);
  var x = _.random(-xSeed, xSeed);
  var y = _.random(-ySeed, ySeed);

  TweenMax.to($blob, speed, {
   x: x,
   y: y,
   ease: Power1.easeOut,
   opacity: 0,
   rotation: rotation,
   scale: scale,
   onStartParams: [$blob],
   onStart: function($element) {
    $element.css('display', 'block');
   },
   onCompleteParams: [$blob],
   onComplete: function($element) {
    $element.css('display', 'none');
   }
  });
 });
}
```

```css
@import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Sigmar+One);

body {
 background: #3da1d1;
 color: #fff;
 overflow: hidden;
}

.congrats {
 position: absolute;
 top: 0px;
 width: 550px;
 height: 100px;
 padding: 20px 10px;
 text-align: top;
 margin: 0 auto;
 left: 0;
 right: 0;
}

h1 {
 transform-origin: 50% 50%;
 font-size: 50px;
 font-family: 'Sigmar One', cursive;
 cursor: pointer;
 z-index: 2;
 position: absolute;
 top: 0;
 text-align: center;
 width: 100%;
}

.blob {
 height: 50px;
 width: 50px;
 color: #ffcc00;
 position: absolute;
 top: 45%;
 left: 45%;
 z-index: 1;
 font-size: 30px;
 display: none; 
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.5.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/underscore.js/1.8.2/underscore-min.js"></script>
<script src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/gsap/1.18.0/TweenMax.min.js"></script>

<div class="congrats">
 <h1>Parabéns!<br>Bacco</h1>
</div>
```

Muitos candidatos de qualidade, que todos continuem contribuindo para um SOpt melhor.

Comment: Melhor mensagem de parabéns :)

Comment: Muito bom mesmo, muito obrigado pelo capricho. Eu vi quando foi postada, mas era tanta informação simultânea (eu ainda estava me adaptando com uma avalanche de coisas e sinalizações novas) que eu cheguei a ver seu post, gostei muito mas acabei cometendo o deslize de não agradecer na hora e acabou passando batido depois. Obrigado mesmo! Esses gestos tem muito valor.

Answer (score 27):

Parabéns ao Bacco, tenho certeza que a escolha da comunidade foi acertada e contribuirá de forma positiva para que a comunidade continue nos trilhos e que melhore mais ainda. Você sempre fez muito e poderá fazer mais ainda.

Answer (score 22):

Parabéns ao Bacco, que sempre contribuiu tanto para o site. Bem-vindo à equipe de moderação!

Queria também registrar que esta deve ter sido a eleição com mais candidatos de alto nível que este site já teve. Só tínhamos uma vaga, mas se houvesse mais, certamente seriam preenchidas por usuários excepcionais. Meus parabéns a todos que participaram!

Answer (score 21):

Meus parabéns Bacco! te desejo boa sorte nesta jornada... tamo junto o/

[image: High Five]

O Stackoverflow em Português é casa de muita gente, e tem recebido mais gente a cada dia, então conto com você para cuidar bem dela. E também para guiar a comunidade pela liderança e moderação.

Answer (score 17):

Parabéns, Bacco. Tenho certeza que você será um excelente moderador e que a comunidade certamente fez uma boa escolha ao elegê-lo. És um usuário experiente, maduro, preparado e equilibrado, decididamente um excelente nome para assumir esta posição.

Agradeço também ao utluiz por ter levado essa árdua tarefa nas costas por tanto tempo, mas que devido aos rumos que a vida toma, agora tem que deixar essa posição. Desejo-lhe muito sucesso aqui ou onde quer que seja.

Quanto a mim, agradeço a todos aqueles que me depositaram seus votos de confiança. Quem sabe, no futuro chegará a minha vez também.

Fico feliz por termos tido uma eleição com excesso de bons candidatos, diferente do que acontece em tantas outras ocasiões onde temos que escolher o menos pior.

Answer (score 14):

Parabéns, Bacco.

Você é um mito!

[image: Bacco 2018]

Comment: ahahahahahahahah

Answer (score 13):

Parabéns @Bacco! Meus sinceros votos de sucesso nessa nova jornada.

Answer (score 9):

Parabéns Baco, creio que farás um ótimo trabalho aqui!
Sucesso nesta "nova etapa", que diria apenas com mais formalidade e poderes, pois sempre vi você atuando aqui no SOpt, estou certo que nossa comunidade só tem a ganhar com a sua colaboração!

Answer (score 8):

Parabéns Bacco, boa sorte!

Tenho certeza que pelo seu tempo e dedicação a comunidade você fará um ótimo trabalho.

Answer (score 8):

Parabéns Bacco, e também a todos que participaram!!
Realmente esse ano estava difícil, excelentes opções.

Boa sorte!

Answer (score 2):

Parabéns Bacco! Pelo que analisei você possui um comportamento exemplar na comunidade e será um ótimo moderador.

Answer (score 1):

Parabéns!

Quero aprender a usar esta ferramenta, será que tem algum material de como usar as ferramentas principalmente de execução de fontes (exemplos) que já por aqui?

Boa sorte Bacco!

Comment: https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5752/quando-devo-usar-o-snippet-e-quando-n%C3%A3o-devo